# How to simulate detailed touch movements using adb without root

Tags: android, adb, touch, gesture

I am trying to write a program that record what your do on screen and replay it all using adb.
currently I was able to finish the record part using `adb shell getevent -t /dev/input/event4 > touch_events.txt` to grabe all the touch events into one file.

but now I am stuck on how to replay it.

I firstly considered about `adb shell input tap` and `adb shell input swipe`, but adb tap is not continuous. and adb swipe is continous but only receive start and end points. it can't simulate more detailed gestures.
so I deside to use low level commend like `adb shell sendevent` to send all events back. this is easier. but when I use it I get `sendevent: /dev/input/event4: Permission denied`. means i may need a root permitission to do that. but I don't want to root. is there another way to simlate the events i grabe from `getevent` without root?

Comment: Looking at the old Java code of the `input` command the swipe command is basically a timed combination of two calls to `InputManager.injectInputEvent` which is a hidden API. I don't see a problem writing your own version of `input` that allows more than start and end-point of a swipe: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.2_r1/cmds/input/src/com/android/commands/input/Input.java

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/swipe which demonstrates how to use multiple segments in swipe (https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/keep-swipe.gif)